# Load more pages in TTLauncherView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

In my implementation of TTLauncherView, only loads the first page. Why?

I have 47 items in array, 47 items div 9 items by page, I should have 6 pages.

Thanks for helping.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {      


NSMutableString *jsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];

NSArray *photos = [[results objectForKey:@"photosets"] objectForKey:@"photoset"];

launcherView = [[TTLauncherView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
launcherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
launcherView.delegate = self;
launcherView.columnCount = 3;

launcherView.persistenceMode = TTLauncherPersistenceModeNone;
NSMutableArray *itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSDictionary *photo in photos)   
{

     NSString *iconURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_s.jpg", 
     [photo objectForKey:@"farm"], [photo objectForKey:@"server"], [photo objectForKey:@"primary"], [photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];


     NSDictionary *title = [photo objectForKey:@"title"];
     NSString *itemTitle = [title objectForKey:@"_content"];
     TTLauncherItem *itemMenu = [[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:itemTitle
                                                                 image:iconURLString
                                                                   URL:nil 
                                                             canDelete:NO] autorelease];

     [itemArray addObject:itemMenu];     

}

launcherView.pages = [NSArray arrayWithObject: itemArray];
[self.view addSubview:launcherView];  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, TTLauncherView doesn't break up the TTLauncherItem's into pages automatically. You need an array of arrays. All of the launcher item's in the first array will be on the first page, all the launcher item's in the second array will be on the second page etc. It has been a long time since I've used it, but I think that's how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My modified code with the hint of @Darren

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {      

NSMutableString *jsonString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
NSDictionary *results = [jsonString JSONValue];    
NSArray *photos = [[results objectForKey:@"photosets"] objectForKey:@"photoset"];
NSMutableArray *itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *pageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSNumber *countPage = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:0];

for (NSDictionary *photo in photos)   
{

    NSString *iconURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://farm%@.static.flickr.com/%@/%@_%@_s.jpg", 
                               [photo objectForKey:@"farm"], [photo objectForKey:@"server"], [photo objectForKey:@"primary"], [photo objectForKey:@"secret"]];

    NSString *photoCount = [photo objectForKey:@"photos"];
    NSDictionary *title = [photo objectForKey:@"title"];
    NSString *itemTitle = [title objectForKey:@"_content"];
    TTLauncherItem *itemMenu = [[[TTLauncherItem alloc] initWithTitle:itemTitle
                                                                image:iconURLString
                                                                  URL:nil 
                                                            canDelete:NO] autorelease];
    itemMenu.badgeValue = photoCount; 

    [itemArray addObject:itemMenu];
    int value = [countPage intValue];
    countPage = [NSNumber numberWithInt:value + 1];
    if (countPage == [NSNumber numberWithInt:9]){
       countPage = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0]; 
       [pageArray addObject:itemArray];
        itemArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    }

}
[pageArray addObject:itemArray];

launcherView = [[TTLauncherView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
launcherView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
launcherView.delegate = self;
launcherView.columnCount = 3;    
launcherView.persistenceMode = TTLauncherPersistenceModeNone;    
launcherView.pages = pageArray;    
[self.view addSubview:launcherView];      

}
```